# How to update axis in a chart with dispatch events d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've posted a **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/09TwO5gY3UXJS6tWO2ia?p=preview)** **(UPDATED)**, a simplified version of [Mike Bostocks](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5872848) chart where I'd like the y-axis to be dynamic.

Normaly I'd just put the `y.domain` and call the `yAxis` in a "update" function, but this doesn't work in this case, and I understand why. I'm just not sure what I should do to make the y-axis dynamic.

Is it non-dynamic because it's calcuating the max value from all the categories in the domain?

```
.domain([0, d3.max(stateById.values(), function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();
```

What can I do so that it only calculate the selected category? (and re-calculate on change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it non-dynamic because it's calcuating the max value from all the categories in the domain?

Yes that is correct.

> What can I do so that it only calculate the selected category? (and re-calculate on change)

In statechange.bar, use d.total in domain:

```
y.domain([0, d.total]).nice();
```